# How to stream a video file in nodeJS and pass the stream to telegram bot

Tags: api, bots, telegram

I am developing a Telegram bot which get a mp4 video file from users and sends it as a VideoNote to specific channel or chat. 
I google and realized that sendVideoNota methods cannot send unstreamed files therefore first I've converted the mp4 file to stream and then passed it to the method.
But get some errors. 
 1. Am I on the right path or not?
 2. What am I doing wrong?

```
if(msg.video != null)
        {
            bot.getFile(msg.video.file_id)
            .then(function (video){
                videoPath= "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot" + TOKEN + "/" + video.file_path;
                console.log("Source File path is: ", videoPath);
                videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath);
                console.log("videoStream is: ", videoStream );
                bot.sendVideoNote(chatID,videoStream);
            })
```

Comment: Telegram Bot API doesn't support stream videos.

Comment: Ok then, how should I use the sendvideonote method ? Can send an uploaded video as videonote to a chennl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending a Video Note message via Telegram bot no need to convert the file to a stream video. Download the video to local storage where your script has access to it, then send it as video-note message.